# how to change the format of snippets placeholder variable in ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

how to change the format of snippets placeholder variable in ace editor

```
    if (${1:condition_name}) {
         ${2:body}
    }
```

the above snippet code will be displayed in the editor as

```
if(condition_name){
      body
}

but i want it as 

    if(<condition_name>){
          <body>
    }

i want placeholder variable inside this <>
i have tried the below one but it is not working
```

```
if (${1:<condition_name>}) {
     ${2:<body>}
}
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? `editor.insertSnippet("if (${1:<condition_name>}) {\n\t${2:<body>}\n}")` seems to work as expected

Comment: @ a user, it is not selecting "<condition_name>" this, it only selects the "condition_name".But i want to select the "<condition_name>"

Comment: which version of ace do you use? it is selected on https://ace.c9.io with v1.4.5

Comment: Thank you.got it